Image-to-Image with U-Net no Skip-connections. Is it real?
In general, U-Net is needed to create another style image, but preserve the structure. For example, a full-fledged drawing from a sketch. Right?
I want to preserve the style, but change the structure. For example, I want to take a photo with crumpled fabric and get unfolded fabric. But i don't wanna use GAN. For this I decided to remove Skip connectors from U-Net that preserve the structure. And also I convolve the input image to the style vector like in GAN. Right?
The problem is that this code trains successfully but only if there is no augmentation in the training database. As soon as I add to the input image (only to the input, since the output should remain unchanged) an angular augmentation of +/- 5, 10 and 15 degrees, then instead of the result I get some noise. If I start training on a dataset of several examples, then the result is correct when applying augmentation. But as the number of examples in the dataset increases, the result gets worse.
But anyway my curve (Loss:MSE) is perfect ))) I mean, even if I get some noise as a result (image), my curve looks like I get a perfect result. Just falling curve. And this is what annoys me the most. I don't understand how it is possible. Even if i get some noise as a result (image) curve is falling down like everything is fine. Approximately 0,09/0.05/0.02/0.01/.... I call it overfiitting just because i don't know what it is. I mean when i don't get correct result but you get falling loss curve it is called overfitting. Right ?
And about capacity of my model. Of course, I thought about it and changed the number of layers, filters in layers and neurons in dense layers but to no avail. So I think there is some conceptual problem here.
I use some examples from training dataset as a validation because i wanna be sure this model can do right at least my training data. But, as i say before, with augmentation i get some noise with perfect loss(MSE). No matter how many epoch i use - result is trash, curve is perfect. Learning rate = 0.00006 * K (K = 5,4,3,2,1). Input/output - image (2562563). Adam.
l2_reg = regularizers.l2(1e-6)
initializer = initializers.he_normal()
   

def build_unet(input_shape=(256, 256, 3)):
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)


    c = layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(inputs)
    c = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(c) 

    c = layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(c)
    c = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(c)

    c = layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(c)
    c = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(c)

    c = layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(c)
    c = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(c)

    c = layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(c)
    c = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(c)

    c = layers.Conv2D(512, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(c)
    c = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(c)


    # Bottle-neck
    b = InstanceNormalization()(c)
    
    b = layers.Reshape((-1,))(b)
    b = layers.Dense(1024, kernel_regularizer=l2_reg,)(b)
    b = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(b)

    b = layers.Dropout(0.2)(b)

    b = layers.Dense(1024*4*4, kernel_regularizer=l2_reg,)(b)
    b = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(b)
    b = layers.Reshape((4,4,1024))(b)


    # Декодер
    d = layers.Conv2DTranspose(512, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(b)
    d = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(d)

    d = layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(d)
    d = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(d)

    d = layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(d)
    d = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(d)

    d = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(d)
    d = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(d)

    d = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(d)
    d = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(d)

    d = layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(d)
    d = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(d)


    outputs = layers.Conv2D(3, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="tanh")(d)

    model = models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="build_unet")
    return model


unet = build_unet()

adam_optimizer = Adam(
    learning_rate=0.00006*K,
)

unet.compile(optimizer=adam_optimizer, loss='mse', metrics= None)

